# .NET Runtime exception caused by thread unhandled exception

Tags: .net, multithreading, runtime-error, unhandled-exception

I have an `Async` method that closes some browser popups.

Some times the application crashes upon exit with a `.NET Runtime` error (**mscorwks.dll** with exception code **0xc0000005**). I suspect it happends when the `Thread` is forced to terminate, because I can't see the logged "Thread exit" line. Could it be the code inside the `ExtendedIeBrowser` that throws an `unhandled exception`?

You can find the source code below.

```
internal void KeepAliveAsync()
{
    PageController controller = new PageController();
    controller.Initialize(siteWebBrowser);

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        _logger.Debug("Thread start - KeepAliveAsync");
        try
        {
            while (!Program.ShouldAbortBackgroundOperations())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (controller.TryCloseTimeoutWarningPopup())
                    {
                        _logger.Info("KeepAliveAsync: Closed popup successfully");
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.ErrorException("KeepAliveAsync", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("KeepAliveAsync", ex);
        }
        _logger.Debug("Thread exit - KeepAliveAsync");
    });
    thread.Name = "KeepAliveAsync";
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

The `PageController` uses this class:

```
public class ExtendedIeBrowser : IE
{
    private IntPtr hwnd;
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public ExtendedIeBrowser(WebBrowser webBrowserControl) : base(webBrowserControl.ActiveXInstance, false)
    {
    }

    public void Initialize(WebBrowser webBrowserControl)
    {
        hwnd = webBrowserControl.FindForm().Handle;

        // Start the dialog watcher or else the browser won't be able to attach the handler.
        StartDialogWatcher();
    }
    public override IntPtr hWnd
    {
        get
        {
            return hwnd;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And this is:

```
    internal static bool ShouldAbortBackgroundOperations()
    {
        bool should = true;

        try
        {
            should &= Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Count(f => f.ShowInTaskbar) == 0; // at least one form is shown in the taskbar
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("ShouldAbortBackgroundOperations", ex);
            should = false;
        }

        return should;
    }
```

The method that closes the popup(literally it's a div inside a web page):

```
    internal bool TryCloseTimeoutWarningPopup()
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            Div glassPane = Browser.Div(Find.ByClass(PageConstants.ModalGlassPaneClass));
            if (glassPane.Exists) // there is a popup
            {
                Div parent = (Div)glassPane.Parent;
                if (parent.InnerHtml.Contains(PageConstants.WarningLoggingOutPrimaryKeyword)) // correct content on popup
                {
                    WatiN.Core.Button button = parent.Divs[0].Buttons[0];
                    ClickOnElement(button);
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("CloseTimeoutWarningPopup", ex);
            throw;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

What if the program is closed after the Abort checking and CloseTimeoutWarningPopup() is executed? I noticed that at some point after I closed the app, the `if (glassPane)` row was waiting for the element to show up and tried to access a disposed object. Could it be that object's memory address no longer available and therefore denied?

Comment: I guess you get a ThreadAbortException? This happens if someone  (forcibly) stops your thread. You could use a ManualResetEvent (or something) to savely stop your thread. You could also add an eventhandler to the Current's Appdomain UnhandledException event and log it there (but depending on the error it may not be called).

Comment: The log doesn't contain any exception at all. I do have an UnhandledExceptionHandler in the Program.cs, but it hasn't logged anything. ManualResetEvent might be nice, I need to see if it really helps with this situation.

Comment: I think you need to stop the KeepAlyveAsync thread in the ExtendedIeBrowser's dispose method and wait for it to exit (or at least give it the chance to finish). Otherwise the thread may still run and access already disposed data (I guess, because I am not quite sure I understand your code example). You could use a ResetEvent in the backgroundthread to check if it has been "Set" in the Dispose.

Comment: Would a try-catch in the dispose be enough to just swallow the exception, since the thread is supposed to terminate?

Comment: you could do a try/catch and stop/kill the thread:

`thread.Join(); // would at least whait 5 seconds - since this is your sleep duration`

or use 
`thread.Join(0); `

or just use Abort()

Comment: The exception you've received is an Access Violation, which likely means some native code in question is accessing an invalid pointer. Also, why do you throw an exception explicitly at the top of your code?

Comment: I managed somehow to replicate the error, I'll post the code of the method that closes the popup along with a new theory.

Comment: Try Application.ExitThread() ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that some controls that the `controller` was trying to access, were disposed before the thread termination, causing the **access violation exception**.